# Why the following is not a tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

Say we have an arbitrary coordinate system, in which a position vector is represented by: $$\vec V=Z^i\vec Z_i$$

Where $\vec Z_i$ is a covariant basis. Now $\partial {\vec Z_i}/\partial Z^j$ term has 9 elements (assuming 3D polar cordinates). The book says this term is not a tensor, but I am unable to understand exactly why it is not a tensor. I mean $\partial {\vec V}/\partial Z^k$ is tensor, but why the above partial derivative term is not a tensor.

In other words, how to prove if something is not a tensor.

Kindly help.

Comment: Look at how the object transforms under a change in coordinates.  Then compare the result to the tensor transformation law.  (Your notation confuses me a little so I can not be more precise!)

Comment: What does $\frac{\partial\vec{Z_i}}{\partial Z^j}$ even mean? The basis vector $\vec{Z_i}$ isn't a function of $Z^j$, which is a coordinate of $\vec{V}$.

Comment: @OscarCunningham: Example: $\partial {\vec e_\theta}/ \partial r$ - this is well defined

Comment: Mhm, no... In order to differentiate vectors you need an operation called covariant derivative.
Well, at least that is the modern treatment. What book are you reading?